# Alternative methods to transfer BTC from an old Coinbase multisig Vault

Tags: wallet, multi-signature

Issue: I am trying to access funds I had stored in a legacy Coinbase Vault 2/3 multisig wallet using the Coinbase multisig recovery tool (https://coinbase.github.io/multisig-tool/) . I have all of the necessary information to access the wallet, including the Coinbase xpubkey, the Shared xpubkey and the User xpubkey. Additionally, I have both the User seed and the Shared seed (encrypted) including the password.

However, I am encountering an issue with the recovery tool whereby the Vault wallet balance is not displaying upon entering in the xpubkeys in Step 1. Upon further research, it appears that there is an issue with the recovery tool referencing a Bitpay API endpoint that is no longer active. As such, the Coinbase multisig recovery tool is no longer functional. For reference, see the Reddit post and Bitcointalk forum post I'm referring to. Note, that I am experiencing the same issue described in the Reddit post (i.e. I have all of the necessary information to access the vault wallet).

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinBeginners/comments/ndvhom/coinbase_multisig_vault_recovery_tool_wtf/
2. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5316286.0

Therefore, my question is, what are some other alternative methods to access the funds in my legacy Coinbase Vault 2/3 multisig wallet? Note, that the options should be prioritized in terms of technical complexity, with less technical methods preferred.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is not an "answer" but if you have everything you say you have it should be possible to access the BTC and send it to another wallet.
I thought I had the password but in testing it, the password did not work.  I reference that in this post.
[how to test decryption of shared seed for a multisig vault](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/111851/how-to-test-decryption-of-shared-seed-for-a-multisig-vault)

Before beginning attempts to liberate your BTC, I would advise you test your password on your encrypted shared seed.

If that works (meaning you do not get an error), congratulations, you have 2 of the 3 keys required to move the funds.  It gets more technical from here, especially to do this yourself.

I would advise reading through this post [recover Coinbase multisig wallet to Electrum?](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5381583.msg58999396#msg58999396) and see if that helps out.  It doesn't spell out the process entirely but will give you an idea what needs to happen.

Answer (score -1):

The original project has long been abandoned. Use this [updated project](https://github.com/pilsnerbeer/multisig-tool-fixed) that fixes the broken things in the original repo and is fully functional as of 2023

Comment: Looking at the repo, it is not immediately obvious whether it is safe to use as the commit history from the original project is not preserved. I would recommend carefully reviewing all of the code before using it.